# FTP Password (not private key-value pair) for EC2 Instance

Tags: password, ftp

I am using AWS EC2 instance and I can connect to it using username and key-value pair (file). But I'd need to connect (over Wordpress) to the server and it's asking me to enter a password.

How and where can I find the password which I can type in? (The only password, or better said private key, I am familiar with is in the .pem file)

Here is the screenshot: https://prnt.sc/gAdr9Y0DSaJb

Thanks!

Comment: You'd need to set up your own FTP server for this if you don't have one already. What account owns the files you're trying to change? If it's root, you'll need to make a different account for that. It's probably that account you'll need to set up a password for.

Comment: That's the site import screen? I'm not sure why it would need direct disk access for that. Not that I've done it myself, but any images to upload etc. can be done from normal WordPress APIs. That sounds wrong to me.

Comment: @Rup Thanks for the reply. I followed this tutorial to set up the site: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8Uofkq718n8 All steps are completed as in the tutorial. Afterwards I wanted to upload a theme and then I got the error message described in the question. I am not sure if FTP server exists (based on the tutorial). Do you have ideas how to proceed further? Or perhaps you have a better tutorial on how to set up WP on AWS. Thanks!